# Best practice for PHP float usage

Tags: php

I've read the [Floating-Point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/php/) about using the float type in PHP. The answer is using the BC Math extension. Using strings can represent the float as an exact type and prevent float and integer issues.

Meanwhile I haven't found any good examples on Github and this site working with the BC math extension. What is a clean way to force PHP to use strings, how to evaluate them?

Especially what is the best way to use the BC Math extension with MySQL DECIMAL data types?

My example test with PHP 5.4.10, the right answer is: 0.2999999999996

```
<?php
bcscale(13);

$a = '0.3';
$b = '0.0000000000004';

echo $a-$b; // 0.3
echo '<br />';
echo bcsub($a, $b); // 0.2999999999996
echo '<hr />';

$a = "0.3";
$b = "0.0000000000004";

echo $a-$b; // 0.3
echo '<br />';
echo bcsub($a, $b); // 0.2999999999996
echo '<hr />';

$a = 0.3;
$b = 0.0000000000004;

echo $a-$b; // 0.3
echo '<br />';
echo bcsub($a, $b); // 0.3000000000000
echo '<hr />';

$a = '0.3';
$b = '0.0000000000004' + 0;

echo $a-$b; // 0.3
echo '<br />';
echo bcsub($a, $b); // 0.3000000000000
echo '<hr />';

$a = (string) 0.3;
$b = (string) 0.0000000000004;

echo $a-$b; // 0.3
echo '<br />';
echo bcsub($a, $b); // 0.3000000000000
echo '<hr />';

$a = strval(0.3);
$b = strval(0.0000000000004);

echo $a-$b; // 0.3
echo '<br />';
echo bcsub($a, $b); // 0.3000000000000
?>
```

Comment: um, what's wrong with the first and second case? If you want to know the "best" option, single quotes '' are better than double "" because PHP will take extra time filling in variable names and escape sequences if you use double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer Dave, using these single quotes does the work. How will I be sure that I have the value in the right type before data may get lost. For example when fetching rows from mysql

Comment: @Dave that's simply not true with any recent php version. Please read [this article](http://nikic.github.com/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html).

Comment: @Maerlyn I wasn't aware of the statistics, but OK. Seems what I said is perfectly true with regard to that article. PHP does extra work, although the time difference is negligible and at compile-time. Single quotes are the best option, so far as there is a "best" option. Back on track: Mike: according to the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php), you will get strings (not numbers) from mysql functions. So this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that gives me confidence :)

Answer (score 4):

The best way is not to use BC Math but start using GMP. Just have a look [on benchmark](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/math/intro.html). GMP is up to 30 times faster then BC Math.

I use DECIMAL(12, 0) AND DECIMAL(27,0) and php start suck apr. at 10^19 and greater. Demo:

```
//PHP Version 5.3.10,  FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE amd64

$a = pow(10, 18);
var_dump($a, $a > ($a - 1), ($a - 1) > $a, ($a - 1) == $a, ($a - 1) === $a);
// int(1000000000000000000)
// bool(true)
// bool(false)
// bool(false)
// bool(false)

$a = pow(10, 19);
var_dump($a, $a > ($a - 1), ($a - 1) > $a, ($a - 1) == $a, ($a - 1) === $a);

// double(1.0E+19)
// bool(false)
// bool(false)
// bool(true)
// bool(true)
```

I made `Decimal` class, [here is simple implementation](http://pastebin.com/Meysnim8). Later you can implement the same interface but with native php math operations or with BC math or whatever you want. Yupp, there will be overhead for functions calls and objects creation, but we write code that other developers can read, aren't we?

P.S.
Guys from [PHP Secure Communications](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/math/intro.html) has their own implementation - Math_BigInteger, which cover all potential need, but is too heavy for my tasks.

**Update:** since PHP 5.6 GMP implemented [internal operators overloading](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/operator_overloading_gmp), so gmp resources may be used as regular numbers (mostly).